# Sprites not deleting from pygame

Tags: python, memory, pygame

I am creating a game where a player can move up and down, and must dodge items as they move from the right side of the screen to the left. However, once the item is off screen, I would like to delete it. I have tried using del and also removing it from my sprite group that I use to draw (after searching on stack overflow), but I do not think its working. Thank you.

```
for block in self.LevelList: #inside event loop
        if block.rect.x < 0:
            self.all_sprites.remove(block)
self.levY = random.choice(self.yList)
self.LevelList.append(Block(self,0,0,18,171,self.levX,self.levY))
self.levX += 100

self.all_sprites.add(self.LevelList)
class Block(pg.sprite.Sprite): #inside settings doc
def __init__(self,game,x,y,width,height,xpos,ypos):
    pg.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
    self.game = game
    self.image = self.game.BlockSheet.get_image(x,y,width,height)
    self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
    self.rect.x = xpos
    self.rect.y = ypos

def update(self):
    self.rect.x -= 1
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your `for` loop, you loop over a collection `self.LevelList`, but when you want to remove the sprite, you remove it from a collection `self.all_sprites`.

I guess `self.LevelList` and `self.all_sprites` are not the same collection, so removeing the sprite from `self.all_sprites` does not remove it from `self.LevelList`.

If you want to keep both collections, make sure both of them are sprite groups, and simply call `kill()`, e.g.:

```
for block in self.LevelList: #inside event loop
    if block.rect.x < 0:
        block.kill()
```

since `kill()` will remove the sprite from all its sprite groups.

Also, you could do this check in the update method of the sprite itself, like:

```
def update(self):
    self.rect.x -= 1 
    if self.rect.x < 0:
        self.kill()
```

(I assume that, since you talk about sprite groups, you use them to draw/update your sprites)